# A kind of sorting which i couldn't resolve

Tags: sql, t-sql, sorting

i have a query like below:

[image]

and the result is like below:

[image]

what i want to do is to show the package (which last analysisjob was added into it) in the top. I don't want the last added package to be shown in the top. I want the result to be like below:

[image]

is there any way to do it?

Comment: What means _"which last analysisjob was added into it"_? The desired order is not clear at all.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `ORDER BY PACKAGEID, ANALYSISJOBID`

Comment: @astander: then the desired result is incorrect.

Comment: my english isnot that good, i meant that the package which the last analysisjob was added. the last analysisjob was added into 'Su' package. I want all analysisjobs which belong to 'Su' package to be shown in the top like the last picture above

Comment: @ErdemGundogdu: i know, but i don't know how you detect the _last_. There is no datetime column. Btw, i assume you mean _with_ instead of _which_. Side-note: add the query and sample data as text, then we can copy paste column/table-names or even add the sample data to sql-fiddle to test our solution. Also, images and links [will rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) eventually.

Comment: yes, there is no any datetime column. the last means the desc order of ANALYSISJOBID's. i must detect it from ANALYSISJOBID's with these columns that i have.

Comment: @TimSchmelter here is the query.
select 58 PACKAGEID, 'Paçanga Böreği' PACKAGENAME, 126 ANALYSISJOBID
union
select 58, 'Paçanga Böreği', 127
union
select 59, 'Su', 128
union
select 59, 'Su', 129
union
select 59, 'Su', 130
union
select 59, 'Su', 131
union
select 59, 'Su', 132
union
select 59, 'Su', 762721
union
select 106206, '11:30 paketi', 762719
union
select 106206, '11:30 paketi', 762720
order by ANALYSISJOBID desc

Comment: @TimSchmelter i have to reach to the result on the last picture.

Comment: @ErdemGundogdu: next time edit your question instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to order first by the package which has the maximum `ANALYSISJOBID`? You can use a CTE + `MAX(ANALYSISJOBID) OVER (PARTITION BY PACKAGEID)`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT  MaxJob = MAX(ANALYSISJOBID) OVER (PARTITION BY PACKAGEID), t.*
   FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT PACKAGENAME, PACKAGEID, ANALYSISJOBID
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY MaxJob DESC, ANALYSISJOBID DESC
```